# Passing key press event from HTML element to python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a HTML page which is displayed by QWebView control in PyQT. This HTML page consists of an 'input' element as given below

```
    <html>
     <body>
      <input id="username"></input>
     </body>
    <html>
```

The code snippet of python part which display the above html is given below

```
    view = QWebView()
    view.load('myview.html')
    view.show()
```

I am handling the key events of QWebView in python part as below

```
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print event.Key()
```

This works fine; and I can see which key is fired in QWebView.  But once I click in my input element and try to edit few values, those keys are not getting in keyPressEvent. It is internally handled in the html element itself i think.  I just want to pass those key events to my python part simultaneously; I am thinking of little bit hacking kind of work to accomplish this.

Any solution will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using your `QWebView` to get at the [`QWebElement`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtWebKit/QWebElement.html) that will receive the html input.

```
documentElement = view.page().currentFrame().documentElement()
input = documentElement.findFirst('input[id="username"]')
```

Now that you have hold of the `input` you could read it after the `keyPressEvent` or maybe connect direct to the `QWebElement` (this may not be possible).

You can simply recover the text with

```
 print unicode(input.toOuterXml())
```